# Dart/fultter : How can I display Images from API on localhost in emulator

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem when I want to display image emulator that comes from my API on localhost
all the text it's appear,also when I past the image url emulator browser it's shown, but when I display images inside the app widget (NetworkImage(imageUrl) I got the following exception

Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following SocketException was thrown resolving an image codec:
OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 48458

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

## 0      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:84:41)

## 1      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:47:14)

## 2      ImageProvider.resolve... (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:327:17)

## 3      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:160:22)

...
Image provider: NetworkImage("http://127.0.0.1:8000/14176.jpg", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("http://127.0.0.1:8000/14176.jpg", scale: 1.0)

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 48460

my code :
Slider services

```
class SliderService {
  String _baseUrl = 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/api';
  getAllSlider() async {
    return await httpGet('sliders');
  }
httpGet(String api)async{
    return await http.get(_baseUrl + '/' + api,headers: {"Accept": "application/json"} );
  }
}
```

Home screen code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:storeapp/services/slider_service.dart';
import 'package:storeapp/widgets/carousel_slider.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  SliderService _sliderService = SliderService();
  var items=[];
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _getSliders();
  }
  _getSliders() async {
    var sliders = await _sliderService.getAllSlider();
    var result = json.decode(sliders.body);

    result['data'].forEach((data){
      setState(() {
        items.add(
          NetworkImage(data['image_url']
          )
        );
        //print(data['image_url']);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Items : $items");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("MY STORE"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 450,
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            carouselSlider(items),


            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I solve this problem and display the images from localhost without any errors

Answer (score 0):

Have you given the internet permissions in the Android manifest file for debug and main.

Have checked this plugin.

```
https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image
```

Check out using this code if it works

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
        placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```

Comment: Yes I did in both debug and main.
Any text comes from API it's  shown without any problem 
Only Image doesn't shown and gives exception

Comment: Edited the post, if still the error persists just post a sample json.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by putting the ip address of my computer

```
Image.network('http://192.168.1.65/img/${report.image}')
```