# Loading image from localhost to flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to load image in flutter mobile android emulator from localhost, but it is not working (the image is not showing).

```
   CircleAvatar(
         radius: SizerUtil.deviceType == DeviceType.tablet ? 12.w : 13.w,
         backgroundColor: kSecondaryColor,
         backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://10.0.2.2:37211/Files/Registeration/Images/42_30092022074513.jpg'),                                            
         ),
```

I am getting the following error:

```
   ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE 
   ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    The following HandshakeException was thrown resolving an image codec:
    Handshake error in client (OS Error:
    WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER(tls_record.cc:242))

    When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
    #0      _SecureFilterImpl._handshake (dart:io-patch/secure_socket_patch.dart:99:46)
    #1      _SecureFilterImpl.handshake (dart:io-patch/secure_socket_patch.dart:142:25)
    #2      _RawSecureSocket._secureHandshake (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:911:54)
    #3      _RawSecureSocket._closeHandler (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:904:15)
    #4      _RawSecureSocket._eventDispatcher (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:847:9)
    #11     new _RawSocket.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1846:35)
    #12     _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1315:18)
    (elided 8 frames from dart:async)

    Image provider:  NetworkImage("https://10.0.2.2:37211/Files/Registeration/Images/42_30092022074513.jpg", scale: 1.0)
    Image key:  NetworkImage("https://10.0.2.2:37211/Files/Registeration/Images/42_30092022074513.jpg", scale: 1.0)
```

When replace the link of image with URL image from internet, it will work normally. So my assumption, there is something wrong with using the localhost.

Also, when I replace the "10.0.2.2" with "localhost" and run the link on the browser the image will show.

I tried this one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542473/dart-fultter-how-can-i-display-images-from-api-on-localhost-in-emulator) but it doesn't worked for me.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try to change `https` to `http` in the url, since probably there is no TLS/SSL on your localhost. The error indicates that secure handshake fails.

Comment: It does not work. I used https to call api on localhost.

Comment: Should'n it be `http` when calling anything on localhost?

Comment: It works for my. Not sure if it works with everybody or it is by chance.

Answer (score 0):

```
CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: "http://....",
    placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(),
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
 ),
```

[Also Visit this](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)

Comment: I mentioned it in the question. I tried it but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by putting the ip address of my computer.

```
Image.network('http://192.168.1.65/img/${report.image}')
```

It works for me on my android device and emulator